# SwiftUI project builds successfully for simulators but Product > Archive fails with errors in a Swift package

Tags: swift, build, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I created my first Swift package by following [this article on medium](https://medium.com/better-programming/build-reusable-swiftui-component-libraries-with-the-swift-package-manager-23343681a8f3) and added it to a Swift project. I can build and run the project containing the package (and many other packages) on simulators fine, but Product > Archive generates errors in my Swift package. The errors all seem to suggest that SwiftUI has not been imported, when it has.

Here's a snippet of the code with a few of the errors:

```
import SwiftUI // I AM IMPORTING SWIFTUI!

@available(iOS 14.0, OSX 11.0, *)
public struct MyStruct: View { // ERROR: Cannot find type 'View' in scope
    @State private var destinationValue: Double // ERROR: Unknown attribute 'State'
    @Binding private var value: Double // ERROR: Unknown attribute 'Binding'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add supported platforms to your Package.swift.

This could look like this:

```
platforms: [
    .iOS(.v13)
]
```

Bernhard

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice if an error message said "Swift package XYZ is missing supported platforms in its Package.swift file."